# Не получается вывести комментарии в django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # auth_user_model - это кастомная модель пользователя, она наследуется от AbstractUser, в ней добавлено поле возраста, но оно здесь не используется

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def add_comment(request, comment_id):
    form = CommentForm()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=comment_id)
    author = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = author
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect("post_detail", post.id)

    context = {"form": form, "post": post}

    return render(request, "ion/comment_form.html", context)
```

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% if not post.comments.all %}
            # инструкция, если к этому посту нет комментариев
        {% else %}
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <b>{{ comment.author }}</b> - <span>{{ comment.date }}</span>
                <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            # если комментарии есть, должны выводиться их автор, дата публикации и текст
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Я не могу вывести данные о комментариях в шаблонизаторе django. У меня есть модели поста и комментария. Прикрепляю код. Форма добавления комментов работает, они видны в админке, но если перейти на detail поста, то данные комментов не выводятся.

В модели есть поля текста комментария, даты публикации, автора и поста, к которому он прикреплен. Во вьюхе задается форма отправки комментария, пост, которому он отправляется (если его нет - 404) и автор ставится автоматически. Если используется метод post, обозначаем использующаюся форму и если она валидна под переменной "comment" сохраняем введенную форму, назначаем автора и пост, для которого создавался коммент и все сохраняем. Эти данные отправляем на страницу detail поста (post_detail). В контекстном словаре передаем переменные "post" и "form". Рендерим это на страницу добавления поста(comment_form, она работает, по ней вопросов нет).
На странице detail поста проверяем, если комментариев нет, выводим сообщение, если есть под переменной comment перебираем их в цикле и выводим автора, дату и текст каждого.
Возможно проблема в том, что pk постов у меня начинаются с пяти, т.к. я удалял некоторые, а pk комментов с другого числа? (Строчки post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=comment_id); comment.post = post.) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @АртемТоршин, у меня работает форма отправки комментариев (та, которая по адресу /<int:comment_id>/comment/), но если перейти на detail поста (/<int:pk>/), то добавленные комментарии не выводятся, срабатывает инструкция {% if not post.comments.all %}, хотя если посмотреть в админке, то комментарии к этому посту есть. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @АртемТоршин, добавил модель post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="comments" on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Добавляем `related_name="comments"` для обратной связи таблиц

Comment: не получается, комментарии так и не выводятся. Я так понимаю, Вы имеете ввиду исправить контекст на "context = {"form": form, "post": post}"? Не судите строго, я новичок в django.

Comment: отфильтровал код, написал подробнее. Помогите, если понимаете, пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы правы, так работает

Comment: Спасибо большое!